Amplitude scaling for the FFT of a logarithmic frequency sweep
I have performed a logarithmic frequency sweep on a system from 1 Hz - 5000 Hz at constant amplitude and acquired the data at a linear acquisition rate of 10000 Hz.
The frequency sweep reference signal is similar to what is produced by the "chirp" function in MATLAB.
When performing the FFT of the reference signal, the amplitude is not constant, but appears to follow a logarithmic curve as well.
What is the correct way to scale the FFT amplitude to obtain a constant amplitude response?
Below is a code which emulates the frequency sweep I've performed.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
% Define parameters
Fs = 10000;              % Sampling frequency (Hz)
T = 1/Fs;               % Sampling period
L = Fs*60;               % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;          % Time vector

% Generate frequency sweep signal
f1 = 1;                % Start frequency (Hz)
f2 = 5000;               % End frequency (Hz)
beta = (f2-f1)/t(end);

y = 0.5*chirp(t, f1, T*L, f2, 'logarithmic');
% y = sin(t*10)

% Calculate FFT
Y = fft(y);

% Calculate the frequency axis
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
df = f(2);

% Normalize the FFT result by the amplitude of the original signal
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1_arb = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1_arb(2:end-1) = 2*P1_arb(2:end-1);

% Plot signal and FFT
figure;
subplot(1, 2, 1)
plot(t, y)
title('Generated Signal')
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude (V)');

subplot(1, 2, 2)
plot(f, P1_arb);
title('Arbitrary Chirp');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('|Y(f)|');


Let's look at the the spectrum on a log/log scale to see what's going on

You can see that the sweep starts indeed at 1Hz and goes all the way up to 5kHz. However the spectrum is not flat, but it's pink, i.e. it falls with 10 dB/decade.
The energy at any frequency is proportional to how long the sweep stays at that frequency. Since a log sweep spends more time at lower frequencies and less at higher frequencies you get this particular slope. In fact, that's the whole point of using a log sweep: you use it if you want a pink spectrum.
If you want the same a level at all frequency use a linear sweep.
